# How to wrap initial of each word in a specific tag with a <b>?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, formatting

I am trying to use the `BeautifulSoup` module with Python to do the following:

Within a div for HTML, for each paragraph tag, I want to add a bold tag to the first letter of each word within the paragraph. For example:

```
<div class="body">
    <p>The quick brown fox</p>
</div>
```

which would read: The quick brown fox

would then become

```
<div class="body">
    <p><b>T</b>he <b>q</b>uick <b>b</b>rown <b>f</b>ox</p>
</div>
```

that would read: **T**he **q**uick **b**rown **f**ox

Using `bs4` i've been unable to find a good solution to do this and am open to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `replace_with()` combined with `list comprehension` - Extract  `text` / `string` from `tag` / bs4 object, process it as text and later on replace the tag with new `bs4 object`:

```
soup.p.replace_with(
    BeautifulSoup(
        ' '.join([s.replace(s[0],f'<b>{s[0]}</b>') for s in soup.p.string.split(' ')]),'html.parser'
    )
)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<div class="body">
    <p>The quick brown fox</p>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

soup.p.replace_with(
    BeautifulSoup(
        ' '.join([s.replace(s[0],f'<b>{s[0]}</b>') for s in soup.p.string.split(' ')]),'html.parser'
    )
)

soup
```

###### Output

```
<div class="body">
<b>T</b>he <b>q</b>uick <b>b</b>rown <b>f</b>ox
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this works exactly how I wished for it to with much less code than I have had thus far! I have just added a space between the f' and <b> to make the output include a space between each word. This is brilliant thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help - Noticed it also and fixed it by adding withespace to `' '.join()` and `split(' ')` to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about how Python parses HTML in detail, but I can provide you with some ideas.

To find `<p>` tags, you can use RegEx `<p.*?>.*?</p>` or use `str.find("<p>")` and walk until `</p>`.

To add `<b>` tags, perhaps this code will work:

```
def add_bold(s: str) -> str:
    ret = ""
    isFirstLet = True
    for i in s:
        if isFirstLet:
            ret += "<b>" + i + "</b>"
            isFirstLet = False
        else:
            ret += i
        if i == " ": isFirstLet = True
    return ret
```

Comment: This actually really helps thank you so much for your comment, I can definitely use this to do the conversion for the '<p>' tags! Just now got to figure out how pull the strings out, parse them to 'add_bold' and then update the html with the returned value.